# How do I convert all files in a folder to a different line ending? (on Windows)

Tags: windows-7, windows

How do I convert all files in a folder to a different line ending (linux or mac)?
I am using Windows.

Right now my approach is to use Winscp to copy to a linux box and then run dos2unix recursively on the folder.

Comment: Sounds like your current approach is pretty good

Comment: You can run dos2unix from WSL as well as from Powershell directly. Details in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692741/how-can-i-make-all-line-endings-eols-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code-unix/61030524#61030524

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Installed Cygwin and Dos2unix in Cygwin

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Command Breakout:

- `.` - Current directory
- `-type f` - Only Files
- `-exec` - Executes the command immediately following it
- `dos2unix` - the command that converts windows line endings to unix line endings.
- `{}` - Represents each result returned by `find . -type f`
- `\;` - terminates the command.

Also, If you just wanted to do a specific file pattern, you could do something like this:

```
find . -name "*.java" -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

- `-name "*.java"` - Only files that end in `.java`.

Comment: you may want `-maxdepth 1` so it doesn't go through subdirectories

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But my use case requires all the files including those in sub folders..

Comment: Installing Cygwin just to run one program seems like massive overkill to me. I would suggest just using the DOS version of the very same program and then a one line command in the shell to run it against all the files.

Comment: @Richard: True, but many of us already have Cygwin and it's tools installed. You can try it too. It will make your Windows more Linux-y and hence, more tolerable. Also, you don't have to look for windows-specific solutions to your command-line problems.

Comment: An explanation would really improve this answer.

Comment: This solution works with Git Bash, too.

Comment: Change dos2unix to unix2dos to go the other way, verified that this solution also works with Git Bash.  unix2dos appears to be smart enough to skip over binary files and only convert text files.

Answer (score 13):

You can install [git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) instead of cygwin32 (or similar) on Windows.  It comes with several unix-like commands (e.g., `find`, `dos2unix`, etc.,) in the `bash` emulation mode.  Once installed, converting files from Windows to Unix file endings should be easy.

Let's say you have your files (ending with the suffix *.java*) in a folder tree called *src* and you want to convert their endings from Windows to Unix ones.

1. Locate *src* in Windows Explorer.
2. Right click and open Git Bash on that folder from Windows context menu.
3. Run: `find . -name "*.java" -exec dos2unix {} \;`.

And that's it!

Comment: Oooh, I _like_ that method!

Comment: This works inside Git-Shell inside SmartGit

Answer (score 3):

I reply because all this reply is hard, and old.
We are in 2023 bro.
Download notepad ++
And replace all `\r\n` with `\n`
this is example that be I for me...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to use dos2unix and unix2dos is excellent.

Here is another way based on your answer.

You can use Gnuwin32 though funnily enough the Gnuwin32 package that has the commands is Cygutils http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/cygutils.htm  so then you'll get unix2dos.exe and dos2unix.exe in C:\Program Files....\GnuWin32\bin and with that in your PATH.

```
C:\somedir>dir<ENTER>
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is DC46-3C68

 Directory of C:\somedir

05/23/2014  01:10 AM    <DIR>          .
05/23/2014  01:10 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/23/2014  01:10 AM                 4 file1
               1 File(s)              4 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  196,129,951,744 bytes free

Do this command to go from dos2unix
C:\somedir>for %f in (*) do dos2unix %f <ENTER>

C:\somedir>dos2unix file1 <-- This runs automatically from you doing the above command
file1: done.

And do this command to go from unix2dos
C:\somedir>for %f in (*) do unix2dos %f <ENTER>

C:\somedir>unix2dos file1 <-- This runs automatically from you doing the above command
file1: done.

C:\somedir>
```

And to test out whether your for %f would do what you want, then use echo or @ECHO e.g.
for %f in (*) do @ECHO unix2dos %f

And you can use xxd to create the files and test they're converted.
xxd  for windows comes with VIM  C:\Program" "Files\vim\vim74\xxd.exe

```
so, i'll create a file, I like this style of command is it allows me to 
create whateer file I want, a dos one or a unix one or anything.  
61 is hex for 'a'       
C:\somedir>echo 610d0a| xxd -r -p >testfile <ENTER>

check the file raw, in its hex
C:\somedir>cat testfile | xxd -p <ENTER>
610d0a

check the file in ascii or unicode
C:\somedir>cat testfile <ENTER>
a

and the following commands just prove that dos2unix and unix2dos work/are working fine.  
C:\somedir>dos2unix testfile <ENTER>
testfile: done.

C:\somedir>cat testfile | xxd -p <ENTER>
610a

C:\somedir>unix2dos testfile <ENTER>
testfile: done.

C:\somedir>cat testfile | xxd -p <ENTER>
610d0a

C:\somedir>
```

note- also in case using a *nix distro, looking at apt-get (apt-cache search dos2unix) the package is indeed (perhaps unsurprisingly!) dos2unix (so installed with apt-get install dos2unix) and that includes along with the dos2unix executable, the unix2dos executable. If you do apt-cache search unix2dos it shows the dos2unix package.